# MemoryStream seems be closed after NPOI workbook.write?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-web-api, npoi

I am using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to convert DataTable to Excel in a ASP.NET Web API project.

But the I got nothing from the response. Here's my code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetExcelFromDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); // create *.xlsx file, use HSSFWorkbook() for creating *.xls file.
    ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet();
    IRow row1 = sheet1.CreateRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; dt.Columns.Count > i; i++)
    {
        row1.CreateCell(i).SetCellValue(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    }

    for (int i = 0; dt.Rows.Count > i; i++)
    {
        IRow row = sheet1.CreateRow(i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; dt.Columns.Count > j; j++)
        {
            row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
        }
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    workbook.Write(ms);
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("{0}.xlsx", dt.TableName);
    return result;
}
```

I set a break point to inspect the `ms.Length` after `workbook.Write(ms)`, but it return a exception : `System.ObjectDisposedException`.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The xlsx variant of NPOI does that while the other one does not. It's just a wierdness of the library which kind of sucks. You can work around it by doing ms.ToArray() and feeding that into a new MemoryStream but it's kind of sad and wasteful.

Comment: @alun Thank you, it works! But it's really wasteful like you said...I will mark it as a work around, and see if it can be slove in the future. Thank you again.

Comment: @alun Thank you. I was using stream.getbuffer() which generated the xlsx but gave a "...corrupt data.." message in MS Excel. Changing the stream.getbuffer to ms.ToArray() fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray()) and Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" fixed the issue. see example  
http://goo.gl/m3xPa7

Comment: Try to set:
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer());

Answer (score 46):

**Update 1/3/2020:** As [Florian Dendorfer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55379161/788051) pointed out, there is an [override](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/commit/14604f8613b53cc8fba3b037f113b9512bbc2340) added in October 2018 to prevent the stream from closing.  Please try the overload first before using this workaround (and upvote Florian's answer!)

Leaving original answer for historical purposes.

---

Another workaround to this issue...which doesn't use multiple `MemoryStream` objects.

Create a `NpoiMemoryStream` class that inherits `MemoryStream`, and overrides the `Close` method:

```
public class NpoiMemoryStream : MemoryStream
{
    public NpoiMemoryStream()
    {
        // We always want to close streams by default to
        // force the developer to make the conscious decision
        // to disable it.  Then, they're more apt to remember
        // to re-enable it.  The last thing you want is to
        // enable memory leaks by default.  ;-)
        AllowClose = true;
    }

    public bool AllowClose { get; set; }

    public override void Close()
    {
        if (AllowClose)
            base.Close();
    }
}
```

Then, use that stream like this:

```
var ms = new NpoiMemoryStream();
ms.AllowClose = false;
workbook.Write(ms);
ms.Flush();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ms.AllowClose = true;
```

At some point between the flush and seek, NPOI will attempt to close the stream, but since we overrode `Close()` and the `AllowClose` flag is false, we can keep the stream open.  Then, set `AllowClose` back to true so normal disposal mechanisms can close it.

Don't get me wrong...this is still a hack that shouldn't need to be implemented...but it's a bit cleaner from a memory usage standpoint.

Comment: What is the purpose to use `ms.Flush()`? MSDN says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.flush?view=net-5.0) that this "Overrides the `Stream.Flush()` method so that no action is performed."
Why at all "NPOI will attempt to close the stream". Isn't it reasonably to leave it opened since we just wrote some data and want to use it?

Comment: This is disgustingly beautiful. Thanks so much for this hack. Don't remove this answer since the overload doesn't exist on word docs, only on worksheets.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if this is still needed, but there's an `overload`

```
Write(Stream stream, bool leaveOpen)
```

where, if you set `leaveOpen = true`, leaves your MemoryStream open

Comment: This is the sanest answer to this question!

Comment: Only available for XSSFWorkbook. When using interfaces this aproach won't be available

Comment: Somehow I don't see such overload of Write. Not even in XSSFWorkbook.

Comment: @papadi, as user 'gangfish' mentioned, you need to look into XSSFWorkBook to find this overload. I too did not find it initially, but later I noticed I was looking in 'POIXMLDocument' class instead of XSSFWorkBook

Answer (score 8):

As [alun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353526/alun) stated above, and also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470173/cannot-access-a-closed-stream-npoi-library) question you can feed the stream into another MemoryStream:

```
...
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using(MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream)
{
    workbook.Write(tempStream);
    var byteArray = tempStream.ToArray();
    ms.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("{0}.xlsx", dt.TableName);
    return result;
}
```

There is a little code smell from having to do this.  However, this is only necessary when outputting .xlsx files due to the way the 3rd party libraries involved handle the stream.

Comment: I have to say that I like this solution better than overriding the class, since it's cleaner.

Comment: This solution is not cleaner. In the case of a large file, it will duplicate its whole contents in memory.

Comment: The overload of Write(Stream stream, bool leaveOpen) seems only available in tonyqus/npoi? I'm using DotNetCore.NPOI from which I couldn't find the overload. So this solution helps me a lot. Thanks Josh.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered similar issues with APIs that close/dispose streams that they 
don't own. I'm not familiar with NPOI, but I assume that the Write method is accepting Stream, not MemoryStream. If that is the case, you can create a wrapper Stream class that forwards all calls (read/write/seek, etc) to the inner stream (your MemoryStream in this case), but doesn't forward calls to close/dispose. Pass the wrapper to the Write method, when it returns your MemoryStream should contain all the content and still be "open".

Additionally, you'll probably need to `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`. After the call to Write your memory stream will be positioned at the end of the stream, so if you try to read from that position it will appear emtpy.

Comment: +1, this works well, is the most memory-friendly, and presents a reusable class when the situation arises again. You can override and forward all the stream methods (except `Close` and `Dispose` - leave those as empty NO-OPs) to the "wrapped" stream with just a few minutes of coding. I called mine `NoCloseStream` so that I knew exactly what it was doing.

Comment: For people directly using NPOI, probably best route is `Write` override if it exists, but I came here because `ExcelMapper`, based on NPOI, has the same problem and no override. This answer helped me solve issue with `ExcelMapper`.